# Visual Studio Code on Mac Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)- Macbook Pro touch pad. I have tried running Visual Studio Code to no avail. Nothing happens, no error message, nothing. It just won't start. I have read articles or using Mac Archive Utility to unzip the downloaded zip file, i still can't get it to run. Has anyone got a solution to this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Mac OS 10.12.5 with a Macbook Pro and recently installed vscode.
Try to redownload the file or maybe restart your computer, you shouldn't have any problems with the installation.